# How do I work out the p-value of many click through rates

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

I have a table which shows pages and click through rates, and I need to know whether a page's performance is down to chance or does perform well. Table looks like:

```
Page name | no_of_clicks | page_views | ctr
page1     |     3        |     6      |  0.5
page2     |     600      |    1800    |  0.33
page3     |     12       |    46      |  0.26
page4     |     50       |    200     |  0.25
...
```

```
CTR = no_of_clicks/page_views
```

Is it possible to add another column to show a p-value?
This is being done in python.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to know exactly what you mean by "[W}hether a page's performance is down to chance or does perform well."

If you believe that the proportion of views that result in clicks
is a valid indication of the performance of a page, then
you could try either `prop.test` or `chisq.test` in R to see
if the click-through rates are significantly different among
the pages:

It seems remarkable that Pages 1 and 3 have much lower counts
than the other two pages. One may wonder why that is true. Also,
whether it is reasonable to include these two pages in our
analysis of the data.

*Test of proportions:* This test does not show significant
differences among proportions at the 5% level because the
P-value $0.06 > 0.05 = 5\%.$ However, the small counts for
some of the pages leads to a warning message that the P-value
may not be correct.

```
x = c(3,  600, 12,  50)
n = c(6, 1800, 46, 200)  
prop.test(x,n)

  4-sample test for equality of proportions 
  without continuity correction

data:  x out of n
X-squared = 7.4009, df = 3, p-value = 0.06016
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4 
0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2608696 0.2500000 

Warning message:
In prop.test(x, n) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

*Chi-squared test:* A Pearson chi-squared test is on a
contingency table `TBL` of these counts is equivalent,
giving the same P-value.

```
TBL = rbind(x, n-x); TBL
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
x    3  600   12   50
     3 1200   34  150

chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 7.4009, df = 3, p-value = 0.06016

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

From this test we can see the exact reason for the warning message:
both of the expected counts (in the first column for Page 1) used in the test are smaller than 5.

```
chisq.test(TBL)$exp
      [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]
  1.944444  583.3333 14.90741  64.81481
  4.055556 1216.6667 31.09259 135.18519

Warning message:
 In chisq.test(TBL) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

However, as implemented in R, `chisq.test` can simulate
a P-value that is more accurate. In this instance, the
simulated P-value still (just barely) exceeds 5%.

There is nothing 'sacred' about the 5% level of significance.
It has often been used as one criterion for determining whether results are
worthy of publication in a journal. To help a company make borderline decision to investigate further whether and why
some pages seem to perform better than others, this result
may be useful.

```
chisq.test(TBL, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TBL
X-squared = 7.4009, df = NA, p-value = 0.05397
```

*A questionable second look:* We noted at the start that, by far, the
most-viewed pages are 2 and 4. We might consider that significance
at the 6% level (for all four pages) warrants looking just at those two pages. (Or we
might have focused only on those two pages from the start because of their relatively much large numbers of views.)

For what it may be worth, those two pages have significantly
different click-through rates. It may be worthwhile to
ponder why those two pages are most viewed and why Page 2
performs best.

```
prop.test(c(600, 50), c(1800,200))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(600, 50) out of c(1800, 200)
X-squared = 5.3245, df = 1, p-value = 0.02103
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.01671496 0.14995171
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.3333333 0.2500000
```

*Notes:* (1) Different statisticians might analyze these data in various ways.
@Mehdi doesn't see anything of interest here, and that may be the right point of view.
I wonder whether a relatively highly viewed page with a CTR of 1/3 might
be worthy of additional thought or investigation.

(2) There is, of course, no question that the four viewing counts
indicate unequal viewing of the four pages. (The null hypothesis is that given the four pages, all four
are viewed equally often; rejected with P=value nearly $0.)$

```
chisq.test(n)

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  n
X-squared = 4346, df = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Answer (score -1):

If **page_views** means the **impression**, so the CTR is a good measure for the visitors interest. The probability doesn't have meaning here.

There is another scenario; you know how many people are in your network if you are measuring the performance of adverts/campaigns; but the number of impressions/pages_views are different as you've shown in that table. This means that something may be wrong in showing the advert; otherwise, CTR shows how people are interacting with the adverts they've seen so the probability is meaningless to me.

ps: I am dealing with the same data in the company I work :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Whilst CTR is a gauge for how well something is performing, the question here is can we trust the CTR? Pages might have a high CTR but only 6 people have viewed the page, so how do we know statistically speaking this page format is well designed and not down to chance?

Comment: As I don't know how your system is working, CTR is fine for the case of showing in-page/pop-up advertisements.
Page_view means that people have seen the page, advert or whatever it is; so 3 clicks for 6 views is very much better than 50 clicks for 200 views.

Comment: One more thing. How do you measure the page view? If one should click on something to open the page, it's another impression/click scenario.